# Passing requirements.txt to Google Cloud Pyspark Batch Job

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run a pyspark script as through a Google Dataproc Batch Job.

My script should connect to firestore to collect some data from there, so I need to access the library `firebase-admin`. When I run the script on Google Cloud through the following command:

```
gcloud dataproc batches submit \
        --project {PROJECT} \
        --region europe-west1 \
        --subnet {SUBNET} \
        pyspark spark_image_matching/main.py \
        --jars=gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar \
        --deps-bucket={DEPS_BUCKET}
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/srvls-batch-0127aaf6-a438-4439-af56-beb1a66f45ed/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import firebase_admin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_admin'
```

I already tried creating a `setup.py` file to generate an .egg file that specifies the dependency along with the `--py-files` flag. This idea was highly inspired by this repo:

http://www.restez-en-bonne-sante-leh.com/?_=%2FGoogleCloudPlatform%2Fdataproc-templates%2Fblob%2Fmain%2Fpython%2Fsetup.py%23BQyskaWdLgo6VQOkV2YyLaeS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize Dataproc Serverless for Spark execution environment it is recommended to use custom container images: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/guides/custom-containers

As an alternative you can take a look at Spark-supported ways of managing Python dependencies: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html